# Acquire session of logged in customer in external script

Tags: magento-1.9, session

I was trying to acquire session of logged in customer in one of external PHP script in the same folder as my Magento installation:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
var_dump($session->getId());
var_dump($session->getCustomerId());

$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
    $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
} else {
    die('Action not allowed. (1)');
}
```

Which output when accessed via the exact domain as my store:

```
NULL NULL Action not allowed. (1)
```

When I'm logged in my store frontend as a test customer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's weird but may be because some security patch or something that changed the session behaviors of Magento. This works now:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Add this line before everything
$coreSessionFront = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// This works now
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
var_dump($session->getId());
var_dump($session->getCustomerId());

// This won't work
//$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
//if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
//    $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
//} else {
//    die('Action not allowed. (1)');
//}
```